# Как добавить ввод переменной с помощью tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

```
import math
from tkinter import *
import time
import random

v0 = 25
#v0 = int(input('v0='))
alf = (random.randint(0, 89))*math.pi/180
g = 9.81
t0 = 2 * v0 * math.sin(alf) / g
x = v0 ** 2 * math.sin(2 * alf) / g
y0 = v0 * math.sin(alf) * t0 - (g * t0 ** 2) / 2
y = v0 ** 2 * (math.sin(alf))**2/2*g
print(y)
m =20
root = Tk()

mx = x*100
my = 800

c = Canvas(root, width=mx, height=my)
c.pack()


def ball(x, y, km):
    c.create_oval(x * km - 5, y - 10, x * km + 5, y, width=5, fill="red")


def ball2(x, y, km, sy):
    c.create_oval(x * km - 10, sy - y * km - 10, x * km, sy - y * km, width=5, fill="red")

c.create_line(0, my - 100, mx, my - 100, width=3, fill="green") # Ось OX
ball(x, my - 100, m) # точка приземления
print(x)
t = 0
while t < 2 * v0 * math.sin(alf) / g:
    time.sleep(0.005)
    c.update()
    t += 0.01`введите сюда код`
    x2 = v0 * math.cos(alf) * t
    y2 = v0 * math.sin(alf) * t - (g * t ** 2) / 2
    ball2(x2, y2, m, my - 100)

root.mainloop()
```

Как добавить ввод данных именно с помощью tkinter?

Comment: Ваши вопросы (это уже не первый, как вижу) отличаются малой кокретностью и отстуствием информации о том, что пытались сделать вы. Кроме того, очень большие куски кода приводите. Пожалуйста, измените вопросы с учетом данного комментария для повышения шанса получения ответа.

Comment: Через объект Entry (однострочное текстовое поле).

Answer (score 0):

```py
#Создаём однострочное текстовое поле:
input = Entry(root, width = 50)
#Помещаем значение из поля в переменную:
value = entry.get()
```